# Can I fill and paint a split porch post or is replacement recommended?

Tags: wood, porch, cracks, wood-filler, column

My wife and I both noticed this week that in the cold temperatures (northern Ohio) the wood on one of the columns on our front porch has split near the bottom, where it contacts concrete (see images below). The house was built in 1926 and very well maintained, though I know some exterior elements have been replaced over time.

My inclination is to wait for warmer weather, then patch it with Gorilla brand exterior wood filler, sand and paint. Thoughts on this approach? Is there anything else that I should be considering, including replacement of the column itself?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A split (check) in a heavy timber is not usually cause for concern, but in this case I suspect that the post may be showing signs of rot from long-term contact with concrete. It's probably not specifically related to the weather.

We seem to see multiple splits (some around the corner). There's also an apparent darkening of the wood. This suggests moisture and maybe decay.

At some point you'll probably want to replace the post, but if it's not very soft it's not urgent. When you do, put a pad of some inorganic, corrosion-resistant material under it. A block of synthetic decking, shaped to match the post or sized as an accent piece, could work well.

You'll need to determine whether the post bears weight. In modern homes the roof trusses are often self-supporting over a porch, but that may not be the case for you. If it is carrying weight, install a temporary post while you work.